# PHPでのフォーム作成で、入力内容の確認画面から入力画面へと戻った時に、フォーム内容が保持されない

Tags: php, form

PHPでのフォーム作成で、入力内容の確認画面から入力画面へと戻った時に、フォーム内容が保持されないです。
Apacheのローカルサーバーとxdomainのレンタルサーバーでは正常に保持されるのですが、お名前.comのサーバーでは保持されません。以下がコードの一部分です。
確認画面のPHP(confirm.php)

```
echo '<form method="post" action="index.php">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hoge" value="'.$_POST["hoge"].'">';
    echo '<button name="backbtn" type="submit">入力ページへ</button>';
echo '</form>';
```

入力画面のPHP(index.php)

```
if (isset($_POST["backbtn"])) {
    $hoge = $_POST["hoge"];
} else {
    $hoge = '';
}

<form method="post" action="confirm.php">
    <input type="text" name="hoge" value="<?=$hoge?>">
    <button type="submit">確認</button>
</form>
```

確認したところ、`isset($_POST[])`が`0`で返されているようで、また、`$_POST["hoge"]`も空なようです。
サーバーの設定に問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: それぞれの環境の情報を提示いただけますか？例えばapacheのバージョンや設定の違いなど

Comment: ローカルのほうは
Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2.10
Xdomainのほうは
Apache 2.2.3, PHP 7.1.x
お名前.comのほうは
Apache 2.2.34, PHP 7.2.4
でした